# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, servicio, observable

estoy realizando pruebas a mis métodos de mi componente, por lo cual me esta dando un problema el observable, tengo el siguiente componente:

```
  export class EgxChangeBlockStatusComponent implements OnInit {

  private loading$:boolean;

  @Input() userAccount: UserAccount = {
    name:'gera',
    lastName: 'kd',
    email: 'gera@gmail.com'
  }

  message:Message;

 // userService: any; //IListInformationService;  //verificar

  //Se agregan los input
  private IdUser : number;
  @Input() userStatus: boolean = true;

  // constructor(){}
  constructor(@Inject(TOKEN_USER_UPDATE_SERVICE) private updateService: IUpdaterUserAccountService
             ,@Inject(TOKEN_ILOADINGSERVICE) private loadingService:ILoadingService,
              @Inject(TOKEN_ITABLESERVICE) private userService: ITableService, 
              @Inject(TOKEN_IINFORMATION) private notificationService: IInformation
               ) { }


  ChangeStatus(){

    if(this.userAccount != null){
      return this.userService.UpdateUserAccount(this.userAccount); 
    }
    else{
      throw Error;
    }   
  } 

  confirm(){ //se crea la función para confirmar 

    this.loadingService.Load(true);

    let  observ$: Observable<any>;

    if(this.userStatus === true)
    {
      this.updateService.BlockUserAccount(this.IdUser).subscribe(
        (response)=> {
         observ$ = response;
        }
      );
    }
    else{
      this.updateService.UnblockUserAccount(this.IdUser).subscribe(
        (response=>{
         observ$ = response;
        })
      );
    }

    observ$.subscribe(response => {
      if (response.code === 201) {
        this.ChangeStatus();
      }
    });

    this.loadingService.Load(false);

    this.notificationService.ShowMessage(this.message);

  } 

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

mi prueba si logra entrar al método pero me marca el error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

```
    export interface IUpdaterUserAccountService {

    UnblockUserAccount(idUser: number): Observable<any>;

    BlockUserAccount(idUser:number):Observable<any>;

   // UpdateUserAccount(user: UserAccount): Promise<any>;
}
```

ese es la interfaz que implementa el servicio de mi componente

y este es mi servicio:

```
    @Injectable()
export class UpdaterUserAccountService implements IUpdaterUserAccountService{

    constructor(@Inject(UPDATE_TOKEN) private updateRepository: IUpdaterRepository) { }

    idUser : number;
    url : string;

    UnblockUserAccount(idUser: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.updateRepository.UpdateById(this.idUser, 'bloquear');
    } //implementar la interfaz 

    BlockUserAccount(idUser:number):Observable<any> {

        return;
     };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Llama al methodo subscribe dentro de los callbacks

```
(response)=> {
         observ$ = response;
         observ$.subscribe(response => {
      if (response.code === 201) {
        this.ChangeStatus();
      }
    });
 }
```

De otra manera `observ$` es, en efecto, undefined

Comment: Mi error, lo siento, hace un momento estaba en la versionen ingles. Enseguida lo corrijo